# Python - SkLearn Logistic Regression: One-by-one train instance

Tags: regression, logistic, python

Here is my question, I have a huge train set so I can't load it in memory and apply this code.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(train_set_df, y_label_df)
```

So, I am looking for a way to train my Sklearn.LogisticRegression model by passing instances one-by-one in order to avoid loading all the train data in memory. Thanks

Comment: With fit you can use the warm_start argument but at least you need 2 labels (i.e. one sample at a time is not possible as all the labels in the training data has to occur at least once in the batch). As an alternative, see partial_fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is Stochastic Gradient Descent on the Logistic Regression objective function. The gist of it is that it estimates the gradient of the objective based on a sample of the data (as opposed to the whole dataset), and tweaks the model parameters based on that estimate to maximize/minimize the objective.

I've not used it but it does seem like SkLearn provides an implementation, [see the partial_fit method off the sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) .

Another library that's likely to be fast for online learning is [vowpal wabbit](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit).